# Windows VBS to delete local printers (doesnt actually delete)

Tags: vbscript

I have the following VBS Script that I am running on windows 10 and while the objPrinter.Delete_ removes the printer so its not listed again next time this script runs but if I look in my Printers & Devices the local printer is still there saying Offline. Any reason why it deletes the printer but it still is listed?

```
Dim strComputer
Dim objWMIService, objNetwork, colInstalledPrinters, objPrinter

strComputer = "."
PrintServer = "SERVERNAME" 'Your Print server name goes here

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colInstalledPrinters =  objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_Printer")

For Each objPrinter in colInstalledPrinters
    If objPrinter.Name = "Adobe PDF" Or objPrinter.Name = "Fax" Or objPrinter.Name = "Microsoft Print to PDF" Or objPrinter.Name = "Microsoft XPS Document Writer" Then
        ' Standard printers we dont want to delete
    ElseIf InStr(objPrinter.Name, "Boca") Then
        WScript.Echo  "DELETING BOCA Printer: " & objPrinter.Name
        objPrinter.Delete_
    ElseIf InStr(objPrinter.Name, "TOSHIBA") Then
        WScript.Echo  "DELETEING TOSHIBA Printer: " & objPrinter.Name
        Set objNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
        objNetwork.RemovePrinterConnection objPrinter.Name, true, true
    Else
        intAnswer = Msgbox("Do you want to delete " & objPrinter.Name & "?", vbYesNo, "Delete Printer")

        If intAnswer = vbYes Then
            objPrinter.Delete_
        Else
            ' They answered no so lets not delete it
        End If          
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Are you running your script under the same account the printer was installed?

Comment: Yes i am running the script under the same account the printer was installed with and it’s an admin.

Comment: Does it removed if you use Windows built-in printer management script (can be found here C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnmngr.vbs)?